# Triple join query displays duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

What causes a query of joined tables to display duplicate data. I have tried group by and it just groups one column and displays the same data for other columns making it useless and distinct wont work. Here is the query that i am running. I have extracted the 3 tables that this query is being run from and its located here: http://pastie.org/4413153
Here is the query:

```
select
pov.products_options_values_id,
pov.products_options_values_name,
pov.color_code,
inv.model,
inv.quantity,
img.id
from products_options_values as pov

left join tbl_inventory as inv
on pov.products_options_values_id = inv.color_id

inner join products_images img
on img.products_id = inv.products_id
where img.products_id = '301'
```

here is a screenshot of the output. (notice 3 records being printed 3 times each.)
[image]

the results i expect from this query is: (screenshot)
[image]

here is a screenshot of the page where this query will be added.

> Sorry the screenshot wont match what i am trying to do but you'll get
> the picture.

[image]

the color names will be used in the select dropdown and the associated color hex values will be used in the colored boxes. the purpose of these boxes are when you mouse over it the image on the left will change to the image id's value that i mentioned needs to be in the query. there is a ajax call that grabs that image ids value and displays its associated image on the left side.

the purpose of tbl_inventory and its quantity count is that if there is a quantity of 0 of a specific color then the color and its associated hex will not be visible on the dropdown or the box.

Comment: Hard to say without more info, but off the cuff guess would be teh outer join to tbl_Inventory add pov.products_options_values_id and inv.color_id to the select list to see if I'm right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are no duplicates.  The 3 "repeated" records each has a different `id` value.  (65,66,67) which makes each one unique. If you remove `img.id` from the SELECT clause and add a DISTINCT, it will remove the "repeated" records.

```
select distinct
pov.products_options_values_id,
pov.products_options_values_name,
pov.color_code,
inv.model,
inv.quantity
from products_options_values as pov
   . . .
where img.products_id = '301'
```

Comment: i actually need those id values to be printed

Comment: @SarmenB., I guess I don't know exactly what you are asking.  Perhaps if you edit your question to include your expected results, I can help further.

Comment: @SarmenB., I've studied your data structure in depth.  There is no way to get what you are looking for without another qualifier.  `img.products_id = '301'` will always return three images (65,66,67) because there is nothing to pick only one of them.  Is there any criteria that is available to choose one image over another (choose 67 over 65 and 66)?

Comment: there isn't, originally this database was very badly designed and i got stuck with it. the only solution i have come up with is building two queries. i'll post the solution i come up with once i get it working. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: this is what i did, sorry what im working in is not a mvc but old style code so i had to work in it. http://pastie.org/4434620  , i just  added a function to check for the quantity(tbl_inventory) and joined the other tables and using the function i checked if the quantity was greater than 0 and if yes display it otherwise dont display it.